# Need help in XSLT for XML Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I would need the help in XSLT 1.0 to transform the following Source XML to Result XML. Not very acquainted with XSLT and also searching for the useful posts in this forum simultaneously. thanks for your help.

**Source XML:**

```
<BomCollection>
  <BomAssyV>
    <sender>Oracle</sender>
    <messageid>ABCD1234EFG</messageid>
    <bomid>1234</bomid>
    <partid>4567</partid>
    <loc>DEL</loc>
    <country>IND</country>
    <cost>30</cost>
    <linenumber>1</linenumber>
    <componentpartid>CID1</componentpartid>
    <componenttype>CTYPE</componenttype>
    <quantityperpart>2</quantityperpart>
  </BomAssyV>
  <BomAssyV>
    <sender>Oracle</sender>
    <messageid>ABCD1234EFG</messageid>
    <bomid>1234</bomid>
    <partid>4567</partid>
    <loc>DEL</loc>
    <country>IND</country>
    <cost>30</cost>
    <linenumber>2</linenumber>
    <componentpartid>CID2</componentpartid>
    <componenttype>CTYPE</componenttype>
    <quantityperpart>30</quantityperpart>
  </BomAssyV>
  <BomAssyV>
    <sender>Oracle</sender>
    <messageid>ABCD1236EFG</messageid>
    <bomid>4321</bomid>
    <partid>8901</partid>
    <loc>MUM</loc>
    <country>IND</country>
    <cost>45000</cost>
    <linenumber>1</linenumber>
    <componentpartid>PID3</componentpartid>
    <componenttype>PTYPE</componenttype>
    <quantityperpart28></quantityperpart28>
  </BomAssyV>
</BomCollection>
```

Result XML:

```
<request>
  <sender>Oracle</sender>
  <messageId>ABCD1234EFG</messageId>  
  <header>    
    <bomid>1234</bomid>
    <partId>4567</partId>
    <loc>DEL</loc>
    <country>IND</country>
    <cost>30</cost>
    <line>
      <lineNumber>1</lineNumber>
      <componentPartId>CID1</componentPartId>      
      <componentType>CTYPE</componentType>    
      <quantityPerPart>2</quantityPerPart>      
    </line>
    <line>
      <lineNumber>2</lineNumber>
      <componentPartId>CID2</componentPartId>      
      <componentType>CTYPE</componentType>    
      <quantityPerPart>30</quantityPerPart>      
    </line>
  </header>
  <header>    
    <bomid>4321</bomid>
    <partId>8901</partId>
    <loc>MUM</loc>
    <country>IND</country>
    <cost>45000</cost>
    <line>
      <lineNumber>1</lineNumber>
      <componentPartId>PID3</componentPartId>      
      <componentType>PTYPE</componentType>    
      <quantityPerPart></quantityPerPart>      
    </line>   
  </header>
</request>
```

Comment: This question is a bit vague. If you're looking for a tutorial in XSLT then google is probably your friend. If you've got something a little more concrete we'd be happy to help.

Comment: Going through w3c tutorials. But need the help on the requirement mentioned above. Need to convert Source XML to Result XML which are given in my post.

Comment: This is a pretty straight-forward transformation. Please provide your current XSLT template and specific questions instead of just asking people to code the entire thing for you.

Comment: @user1948230: I am not aware of any W3C XSLT tutorial (please note that W3schools is not related to W3C). 
You should learn XSLT with [Norman Walsh's tutorial](http://nwalsh.com/docs/tutorials/xsl/).

Comment: We don't wanna do your homework!

Comment: You need to say where you are stuck, why you are finding it difficult. Otherwise this simply looks like a request for free coding and/or free training.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some grouping - have a look at this SO Post : [Applying Muenchian grouping for a simple XML with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783340/applying-muenchian-grouping-for-a-simple-xml-with-xslt). Specifically, look at the reference to [Jeni Tennison's Muenchain grouping guide](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml)

I've assumed here that there is only one `request` output element (otherwise you'll need a second level of grouping), and also that `bomid` and `partid` are tied.

**The XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="bomids" match="BomAssyV" use="bomid" />

  <xsl:template match="BomCollection">
    <xsl:element name="request">
      <!-- We just scrape the first BomAssyV/sender and messageid elements -->
      <sender>
        <xsl:value-of select="BomAssyV/sender"/>
      </sender>
      <messageid>
        <xsl:value-of select="BomAssyV/messageid"/>
      </messageid>
      <!--i.e. Only the first bom in every group-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="BomAssyV[generate-id()=generate-id(key('bomids', bomid)[1])]" mode="group"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="BomAssyV" mode="group">
    <header>
      <bomid>
        <xsl:value-of select="bomid"/>
      </bomid>
      <bomid>
        <xsl:value-of select="partid"/>
      </bomid>
      <loc>
        <xsl:value-of select="loc"/>
      </loc>
      <country>
        <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
      </country>
      <cost>
        <xsl:value-of select="cost"/>
      </cost>

      <xsl:for-each select="key('bomids', bomid)">
        <line>
          <lineNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="linenumber"/>
          </lineNumber>
          <componentPartId>
            <xsl:value-of select="componentpartid"/>
          </componentPartId>
          <componentType>
            <xsl:value-of select="componenttype"/>
          </componentType>
          <quantityPerPart>
            <xsl:value-of select="quantityperpart"/>
          </quantityPerPart>
        </line>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </header>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Transforms this input XML**

```
<BomCollection>
  <BomAssyV>
    <sender>Oracle</sender>
    <messageid>ABCD1234EFG</messageid>
    <bomid>1234</bomid>
    <partid>4567</partid>
    <loc>DEL</loc>
    <country>IND</country>
    <cost>30</cost>
    <linenumber>1</linenumber>
    <componentpartid>CID1</componentpartid>
    <componenttype>CTYPE</componenttype>
    <quantityperpart>2</quantityperpart>
  </BomAssyV>
  <BomAssyV>
    <sender>Oracle</sender>
    <messageid>ABCD1234EFG</messageid>
    <bomid>1234</bomid>
    <partid>4567</partid>
    <loc>DEL</loc>
    <country>IND</country>
    <cost>30</cost>
    <linenumber>2</linenumber>
    <componentpartid>CID2</componentpartid>
    <componenttype>CTYPE</componenttype>
    <quantityperpart>30</quantityperpart>
  </BomAssyV>
  <BomAssyV>
    <sender>Oracle</sender>
    <messageid>ABCD1236EFG</messageid>
    <bomid>4321</bomid>
    <partid>8901</partid>
    <loc>MUM</loc>
    <country>IND</country>
    <cost>45000</cost>
    <linenumber>1</linenumber>
    <componentpartid>PID3</componentpartid>
    <componenttype>PTYPE</componenttype>
    <quantityperpart>28</quantityperpart>
  </BomAssyV>
</BomCollection>
```

**To this output xml**

```
<request>
  <sender>Oracle</sender>
  <messageid>ABCD1234EFG</messageid>
  <header>
    <bomid>1234</bomid>
    <bomid>4567</bomid>
    <loc>DEL</loc>
    <country>IND</country>
    <cost>30</cost>
    <line>
      <lineNumber>1</lineNumber>
      <componentPartId>CID1</componentPartId>
      <componentType>CTYPE</componentType>
      <quantityPerPart>2</quantityPerPart>
    </line>
    <line>
      <lineNumber>2</lineNumber>
      <componentPartId>CID2</componentPartId>
      <componentType>CTYPE</componentType>
      <quantityPerPart>30</quantityPerPart>
    </line>
  </header>
  <header>
    <bomid>4321</bomid>
    <bomid>8901</bomid>
    <loc>MUM</loc>
    <country>IND</country>
    <cost>45000</cost>
    <line>
      <lineNumber>1</lineNumber>
      <componentPartId>PID3</componentPartId>
      <componentType>PTYPE</componentType>
      <quantityPerPart>28</quantityPerPart>
    </line>
  </header>
</request>
```

Comment: Extreme thanks for your help.I will take this up and proceed and verify with different payloads.