# Slightly more complex xslt muenchian grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, muenchian-grouping

another newcomer to xslt here. I have a problem similar to this one - [Applying Muenchian grouping for a simple XML with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783340/applying-muenchian-grouping-for-a-simple-xml-with-xslt) - but complicated by an extra layer of nodes.

I have this XML...

```
<ALLDATA>
  <THIS>
    <ID>datum 1</ID>
    <DATA>datarecord1</DATA>
    <RELATIONSHIPS>
      <rel>
        <relid>rd1</relid>
        <reldata>something</reldata>
      </rel>
    </RELATIONSHIPS>
  </THIS>
  <THIS>
    <ID>datum 1</ID>
    <DATA>datarecord1</DATA>
    <RELATIONSHIPS>
      <rel>
        <relid>rd2</relid>
        <reldata>other</reldata>
      </rel>
    </RELATIONSHIPS>
  </THIS>
  <THIS>
    <ID>rd1</ID>
    <DATA>relrecord1</DATA>
    <RELATIONSHIPS/>
  </THIS>
  <THIS>
    <ID>rd2</ID>
    <DATA>relrecord2</DATA>
    <RELATIONSHIPS/>
  </THIS>
</ALLDATA>
```

... and would like to convert it to ...

```
<ALLDATA>
  <THIS>
    <ID>datum 1</ID>
    <DATA>datarecord1</DATA>
    <RELATIONSHIPS>
      <rel>
        <relid>rd1</relid>
        <reldata>something</reldata>
      </rel>
      <rel>
        <relid>rd2</relid>
        <reldata>other</reldata>
      </rel>
    </RELATIONSHIPS>
  </THIS>
  <THIS>
    <ID>rd1</ID>
    <DATA>relrecord1</DATA>
    <RELATIONSHIPS/>
  </THIS>
  <THIS>
    <ID>rd2</ID>
    <DATA>relrecord2</DATA>
    <RELATIONSHIPS/>
  </THIS>
</ALLDATA>
```

The xslt (1.0) I'm using is obviously way off base so was hoping someone with more knowledge (hi!) could help put me right :)

Here is the useless xslt...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="krel" match="THIS" use="ID"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="appex_user/node">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="THIS[generate-id() = generate-id(key('krel', ID)[1])]" mode="group"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="THIS/RELATIONSHIPS" mode="group">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="RELATIONSHIPS/rel"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('krel', ID)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actually - I've tried all sorts of combinations to no avail.

Comment: Well, `match="appex_user/node"` does not match any of the input you have posted.

Comment: To be safe, shouldn't *DATA* also be part of the key? Even if *ID* and *DATA* were supposed to be linked one-to-one, there might be a situation, where there are *THIS* elements with same *ID* value, but different *DATA* values. Then running the stylesheet with only *ID* on the key would take only one of those *DATA* elements and all others with different values would be lost. Just saying.

Comment: Ach.. the appex_user bit was from the original - I adjusted my tags to make it look more generic instead of using the real tags.

Comment: Re. the DATA tag: yes you're right but in my case it's always the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your XSLT

Firstly you have a template matching "appex_user/node" which is not in your XML. You need to be matching the root element "ALLDATA" here.

Secondly, you use the "mode" attribute when selecting the distinct `THIS` elements. There's nothing wrong with that, but you don't have a template matching the `THIS` element that also uses mode. This means XSLT will use its default template which will not output the `THIS` element, but continue matching its children. I don't think you really need to use "mode" in this case.

Now, you do have a template matching `RELATIONSHIPS` using mode, which will get matched, but when you use the key, you use it with a value of "ID" which will look for an element named `ID` as a child of the current `RELATIONSHIPS` node. But `ID` is not a child. You should use the expression `..\ID` to get the node that is a child of the parent.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="krel" match="THIS" use="ID"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ALLDATA">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="THIS[generate-id() = generate-id(key('krel', ID)[1])]" />
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="THIS/RELATIONSHIPS">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('krel', ../ID)/RELATIONSHIPS/rel"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim - looks good. I'll give it a go when back in work next week :)

Comment: Further to my previous answer - it worked a treat. Thanks again!